# How to convert XPath to GUI elements as sections?

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I have this string as `List`,may be similar to `XPATH` structure.

1. Employee/Entity/Id/
2. Employee/Entity/Name/
3. Employee/Entity/Address/City
4. Employee/Entity/Address/State

Need this `HTML` structure

```
<div class="LevelOne"> 
    <div>
        <p>Employee</p>
    </div>
    <div class="LevelTwo">
        <div>
            </p>Entity</p>
        </div>
        <div class="LevelThree">
            Id: <input type="text" />
                        Name: <input type="text" />
            <div class="LevelFour"> 
                <div>
                    </p>Entity</p>
                </div>
                City: <input type="text" />
                State: <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas would be helpful?

Comment: XPath is used to find elements in XML documents. I think what you need is a XSLT transform that will transform you XML document (you do have one?) using the XPath statements to the HTML. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @vesan, I won't be having `XML` document, this is a similar structure like `XPATH` and so meant the term `XPATH`

Comment: OK, I don't understand the question then. Hopefully someone else will be able to help.

Comment: @Vesan, I updated the question to be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @downvoters, care to comment

Comment: What is `<input type="City" />`? Doesn't seem to be HTML, even HTML5 with lots of input types http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type doesn't have that type. Same for `<input type="State" />`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Sorry it is by mistake, it is a `text` type only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using LINQ to group the path expressions and LINQ to XML to create a HTML structure:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> paths = new List<string>() {
        "Employee/Entity/Id",
        "Employee/Entity/Name",
        "Employee/Entity/Address/City",
        "Employee/Entity/Address/State"
    };

    IEnumerable<XElement> result = GroupSteps(from path in paths select path.Split('/'));

    foreach (XElement el in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(el);
    }

}
private static IEnumerable<XElement> GroupSteps(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> steps)
{
    return GroupSteps(steps, 1);
}

private static IEnumerable<XElement> GroupSteps(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> steps, int level)
{
    return from step in steps
           group step by step.FirstOrDefault() into g
           select g.Count() > 1 ?
            new XElement("div",
               new XAttribute("class", "Level" + level),
               new XElement("div",
                   new XElement("p", g.Key)
               ),
               GroupSteps(g.Select(mg => mg.Skip(1)), level + 1)) :
            new XElement("label", g.Key + ": ", new XElement("input", new XAttribute("type", "text")));

}
```

It outputs

```
<div class="Level1">
  <div>
    <p>Employee</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Level2">
    <div>
      <p>Entity</p>
    </div>
    <label>Id: <input type="text" /></label>
    <label>Name: <input type="text" /></label>
    <div class="Level3">
      <div>
        <p>Address</p>
      </div>
      <label>City: <input type="text" /></label>
      <label>State: <input type="text" /></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which is not quite what you have asked for but I have opted to wrap the `input` elements in a corresponding `label` and did not try to output the level of nesting as a word.